# Child Process Termination in windows

Tags: windows, go, process, child-process

I have .exe application in GO that spawns a child process in windows.
When i terminate my parent process for some reason the child process terminates too.
However when my parent.exe panics and crashed, the child process continue to execute and does not shutdown.

Ideally I was expecting the child process to keep on living if the parent process shuts down(normally or forcefully)

Is the the default behavior of processes in windows?

In addition to above.
I added code to capture any Signal the child process receives if I terminate the Parent Process, It seems that every time i terminate the parent process the child receives an interrupt signal.

Comment: windows nothing do with child process if parent exit (by any reason). but of course child process can communicate with parent, and if parent exit - terminate self. this already depend on specific child process.

Comment: I added code to capture any Signal the, child process receives if I terminate the Parent Process, It seems that every time i terminate the parent process the child receives an interrupt signal.

Comment: what is *signal* ? i don know this. this is not windows related. and of course windows nothing send to child process when parent terminated

Comment: Best guess: you're pressing control-C or control-break.  By default, this will affect all processes in the same console.

Comment: Thanks, Yes i was running the Parent Process from Command Window, I looked at the process hierarchy in the SystInternals, Process Explorer tool. It seems when we run a new Process from the command window, they become child process of that Command Windows Process, and doing a Ctrl-C terminates all the child processes.